# Error! Unknown Op code for conditional MS Word 365

Tags: if-statement, ms-word, conditional-statements, mailmerge

I am trying to do a mail merge and am using the code below.  Note: the {} are made with CTRL +F9.
[image: Error Code]

and I keep getting the above error.  A similar code is use in many other parts of my document and are working fine. [image: Non-Error Code]

Can anyone help with what is triggering this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be surprising if either field in your post was working properly given that neither is properly constructed. Both lack an operator before the first "" and a space between the = and 0

In any event, all you need is:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD MidYear_MAP_Test_Points_Grade_Numeric_}<> "" {MERGEFIELD MidYear_MAP_Test_Points_Grade_Numeric_ \# "0.00,,'Missing'"}}
```

and:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD USATP_4_Points_Grade_Numeric_MaxPoints}<> "" {MERGEFIELD USATP_4_Points_Grade_Numeric_MaxPoints \# "0.00,,'Missing'"}}
```